# Multiple Lines in the Android XML

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to add a multiple lines in the view. Each line segment has two textViews. I know I could able to do it via using Adapter but my overall requirements does not fit into ListView very well.

The following xml only shows the first line but it is not adding the second line to the view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Left"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="[DetailedType]"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Right"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="[CustomerName]"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/XLeft"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="[XDetailedType]"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/XRight"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="[XCustomerName]"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: that's because your first linear layout takes all the height. but the graphical layout editor would have told you that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` on your two inner `LinearLayouts`

Comment: I am going to mark as your answer as long as SOF allows me.